# Passing the data from a first python scripts main function in a second scripts function

Tags: python, traveling-salesman, or-tools, object-type

I'm needing to use some data from the first script in a function in the second script, but not sure how to do this properly in my case.  I hope there is a simple answer, but getting stuck on this, unfortunately.

The end of the first script is

```
def main():

  data = create_data()
  addresses = data['addresses']
  API_key = data['API_key']
  distance_matrix = create_distance_matrix(data)
  print(distance_matrix)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

and the program prints out something like

```
[[0, 486348, 155151, 780965, 761151, 254349], [486474, 0, 594180, 422167, 590566, 262043], [155151, 594054, 0, 888671, 868857, 362056], [781506, 421262, 889213, 0, 295098, 495764], [761786, 590592, 869492, 295059, 0, 612583], [254304, 260708, 362011, 495807, 612769, 0]]
```

I could title this program "scriptA"

In the second  script, "scriptB"  I want to use

```
import scriptA
```

and modify the function in script B that input manually looks like

```
def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['distance_matrix'] = [[0, 383429, 118275, 223206, 209301, 405420], [383498, 0, 413976, 422167, 590566, 262043], [117759, 412902, 0, 335203, 315389, 355002], [223635, 421262, 335387, 0, 295098, 495764], [210227, 590592, 315667, 294775, 0, 612583], [405701, 260708, 354835, 495807, 612769, 0]]  # yapf: disable
    data['num_vehicles'] = 1
    data['depot'] = 0
    return data
```

to include the matrix from the first script automatically.  But I'm not sure of the correct code for doing so.   I tried doing

```
data['distance_matrix'] = scriptA.main()
```

but this doesn't maintain the correct object type that I need.    Some guidance towards the desired syntax to use would be appreciated.

If the further context is useful the `scriptA` and `scriptB` I am using are very similar to example codes from 
https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp
and https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp in the **Google OR-Tools** documentation respectively.

Comment: It is because you are using print and not return in the first function. Also, no need for the: 
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

Comment: Ok,.. I think that helps

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify main function from scriptA. You should return the matrix instead of printing it.
Updated code:

```
def main():
  data = create_data()
  addresses = data['addresses']
  API_key = data['API_key']
  distance_matrix = create_distance_matrix(data)
  return distance_matrix
```

Then calling `scriptA.main()` will return array to you.